# How to set a One-Time only event using DDay iCal

Tags: c#, dday

I am trying to setup a **One-Time** only event using the DDay iCal library.

The FrequencyType lists the following:

```
public enum FrequencyType
{
    None = 0,
    Secondly = 1,
    Minutely = 2,
    Hourly = 3,
    Daily = 4,
    Weekly = 5,
    Monthly = 6,
    Yearly = 7,
}
```

Currently in my application the user is given options for creating a **One-Time** or **Daily** events.

For **Daily** this does the job:

`FrequencyType.Daily`

and this code:

```
Event evt = iCal.Create<Event>();
RecurrencePattern rp = new RecurrencePattern(frequencyType);
evt.RecurrenceRules.Add(rp);
```

I have removed other details for brevity.

How do I go about setting a **One-Time** only event?

Comment: Can you please show the code that allows you to set daily events?

Comment: Thanks for that. It seems to me that you just simply wouldn't add any recurrence rules. Is that not right?

Comment: So why are you asking this question? I'm confused.